# How can I use the same smart object several times in the same PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I am using a smart object in my PSD file that I duplicated 3 times. But when I update the smart object by saving the others don't change.

The objective is when I update one smart-object the others will be automatically change.

Comment: Please [edit] you question to use proper punctuation. As it is now, your question is very hard to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Photoshop Help  /
Work with Smart Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html#duplicateasmartobject)

> **Duplicate an embedded Smart Object**
>
> In the Layers panel, select a Smart Object layer, and do one of the following:
>
> - To create a duplicate Smart Object that is linked to the original, choose Layer > New > Layer Via Copy, or drag the Smart Object layer to the Create A New Layer icon at the bottom of the Layers panel. Edits you make to the original affect the copy and vice versa.
> - To create a duplicate Smart Object that isn’t linked to the original, choose Layer > Smart Objects > New Smart Object Via Copy. Edits you make to the original don’t affect the copy.
>
> A new Smart Object appears in the Layers panel with the same name as the original and “copy” as a suffix.